# Amazon S3 bucket upload image with iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using cocoapod AWS file for uploading

pod 'AWSS3'
pod 'AWSCognito'
pod 'AWSCore'

creating configuration using accesskey and secretkey

```
    let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
   
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

Trying to upload an image with transferutility

```
    transferUtility!.uploadData(imageData! as Data,
                               bucket: S3BucketName,
                               key: fileName,
                               contentType: "image/*",
                               expression: expression,
                               completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith {
                                (task) -> AnyObject? in
                                if let error = task.error {
                                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                }

                                if let result = task.result {
                                    print ("upload successful.")
                                    print (result.response)
                                }
                                return nil;
    }
```

Getting an error at completion handler with

Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={Server=AmazonS3, Transfer-Encoding=Identity, Connection=close, Content-Type=application/xm}